# I have a problem with uploading the image to the canvas in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

In my `MainPage` when I try to run the function(ShowEntity) the image wont show on the background.
When i run it on my player(class in my project) then the image wont show up on the screen.
i tried to change the format few time but i dont find the problem.
i think there is something wrong in the ShowEntity function.

this is an example of how i try to make it work.
`Player _player1 = new Player(500, 500, 150, 150, "ms-appx:///Asssets/Player5.gif");`

```
    public class Piece
    {
        private double _x;

        private double _y;

        public int _width;

        private int _height;

        public string _image;

        public Image _imagesource { get; set; }

     public Piece(double x, double y, int width, int height, string image)//BitmapImage imagesource)
        {
            _x = x;

            _y = y;

            _image = image;

            _width = width;

            _height = height;

            _imagesource = ShowEntity();           
        }

        private Image ShowEntity()
        {
            Image _img = new Image();

            _img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(_image));

            _img.Height = _height;

            _img.Width = _width;

            Canvas.SetLeft(_img, _x);

            Canvas.SetTop(_img, _y);

            GameManager.MyCanvas.Children.Add(_img);

            return _img;
        }
```

Comment: Any updates for this thread ?

Comment: yes i worked it out finally, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks your image was covered by other element, if you want to show element in the Canvas, you need to set [ZIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.zindex?view=winrt-22621#windows-ui-xaml-controls-canvas-zindex) for element.

*Canvas.ZIndex declares the draw order for the child elements of a Canvas. This matters when there is overlap between any of the bounds of the child elements. A higher z-order value will draw on top of a lower z-order value. If no value is set, the default is -1.*

If you want to set image as background, you could set it's ZIndex with samll value. And other way is set Canvas Background with ImageBrush directly like the fllowing.

```
MyCanvas.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.BaseUri, "ms-appx:///Assets/enemy.png")), Stretch = Stretch.Fill };
```